# Como subir múltiples archivos a servidor FTP con asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

Hola buen día estoy haciendo una aplicación para subir múltiples imágenes a mi servidor FTP el problema que tengo es que por ejemplo (Al seleccionar 2 o 3 imágenes este solo sube la primera imagen que se selecciono) y lo que quiero es subir mas de 2 archivos
¿Saben de una forma de hacerlo?
Este es mi código:

```
if (ftpFileUpload.HasFiles)
        {
            string fileName = Server.HtmlEncode(ftpFileUpload.FileName);
            string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);

            if ((extension == ".jpg") || (extension == ".pdf") || (extension == ".png") || (extension == ".doc"))
            {
                foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in ftpFileUpload.PostedFiles)
                {
                    string filename = ftpFileUpload.FileName;

                    Stream fs = ftpFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;
                    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                    byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

                    string filePath = filename;
                    File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(filePath), bytes);

                    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + filename);
                    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User", "Pass");

                    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

                    request.UseBinary = true;

                    byte[] fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(filePath));
                    request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

                    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblNombre.Text = "Solo se permiten Archivos con Formato |.png|.jpg|.pdf|";
            }
        }
```

De antemano Gracias!!!

Comment: Dentro de tu `foreach` debes usar la variable `uploadedFile`, que es la contiene el archivo de cada iteración.

Comment: @Yussef Listo ya funciono al hacer uso de la variable